# Oracle query select data in multi tables

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables.

This is  tableA

[image: Table 1] (invoice,D/O, cost..) and

Table B

[image: Table 2]

(D/O, GRN, Qty)

Now how to use query to show table A include GRN,Qty

See 
[image: Result]

Comment: You should not post code / sample data  as an image: [why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: People have taken the effort to edit your question to display your images. While we prefer text, embedded images are better than links. So please take care when editing your question not to revert the work of others.

Answer (score 0):

You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to retrieve all the records from table `A` with matched records from table `B`.

Guessing at the join criteria because your question doesn't say what they are:

```
select a.*
       , b.grn
       , b.grn_line
       , b.qty_grn
from a
     left outer join b
           on a.do = b.do
           and a.do_line = b.do_line
           and a.invoice_line = b.grn_line
```

Comment: Thank you, but invoice_line and GRN_line is different can not compare. And when i use your query so D/O with line 1 will double check in table B and combain with table A --> create 4 lines for D/O "1000001-line1"

Comment: As I said, I was making a guess as you hadn't provided the business logic. What I suggested was the only way I can see to produce your required output from the posted inputs. If you don't like my answer then please **edit your question** to include the rules for joining the two tables. If you don't know those rules you need to ask your teacher to fill in the gaps.